# Spring OAuth2 Server is not responding with refresh token after authorization code flow

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have setup an OAuth2 auth server with the main purpose of using an authorization code flow. From what I can gather, the flow is working as I'm able to get a valid access_token at the end of the flow but the problem is I'm not getting a request_token response field. I'm not sure if I'm meant to do something differently to what I've done, but I believe all I had to do to get this was to add "request_token" in the authorizedGrantTypes parameters (which I have done). I will most the relevant setup code below.

**AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter**

```java
@Import(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    KeyPair keyPair;
    RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

    public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, KeyPair keyPair, RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory,
                                     PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.keyPair = keyPair;
        this.redisConnectionFactory = redisConnectionFactory;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("web")
                    .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("noonewilleverguess"))
                    .scopes("resource:read", "resource:write")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                    .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/login-two");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore(redisConnectionFactory))
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        return new RedisTokenStore(redisConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(this.keyPair);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration**

```java
@Configuration
public class JwtSetEndpointConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .mvcMatchers("/.well-known/jwks.json")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/.well-known/jwks.json").permitAll();
    }


}
```

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyPair keyPairBean() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        //TODO:drt - probs change
        KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        gen.initialize(2048);
        return gen.generateKeyPair();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**The authorization code flow response**

I first send a GET request to:

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=web&state=8781487s1
```

Example Redirection: http://localhost:8080/login-two?code=N-U9XJ&state=8781487s1

So then I send a POST request to http://localhost:8080/oauth/token with Basic Auth

[image]

This is the example response I'm receiving, with no refresh_token field :

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTc2MjY1NzQsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9VU0VSIl0sImp0aSI6ImRENUplcWI3QlhHTkd0WkI1QVU4akhNbGR1YyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IndlYiIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlc291cmNlOndyaXRlIiwicmVzb3VyY2U6cmVhZCJdfQ.D5XKotYYAZkKtZNWdD-wirtoi3prU3CCmibIiQF5kodbXeK5ETdZ5k8CgSBLd7Aq-XEdhYXUEbtzzI0vf1vHf_MyhPFy_owldm_JJf2-2z9jNoU2BSnGMp6TCM00pCSMwbk57paLRZouryHEhTdvixVDmez2e1KmMVmXP6NypARB3Sp5SD2sZ2JN7FBQdkQ0OMVChjAQMTy1M3mDiT5dpT7iD7JxKRFTmD7qKYSF_gbQi6mEF3oH4j40TGI_CpyP3kKdDh4kiEfNeFd84YNHGYZACsYHfjoJrtJV1ECoeLph5CpmSpzt0lhOlzy8Q98OsPR8SdRt5Ou9N-BFmftZDw",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 13462,
    "scope": "resource:write resource:read",
    "jti": "dD5Jeqb7BXGNGtZB5AU8jHMlduc"
}
```

Hopefully one of you guys can help, as at this point after trying things out and looking up online I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to fix this so it now returns a refresh token after the authorization flow. All I had to do was add the DefaultTokenServices bean and make sure to setSupportRefreshToken to true.

```java
@Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```